# Test the number of json object

Tags: android, json

i made this but i want to change while loop to do-while it's inferior to the maximum JsonObjet for example if i have 2 Json objects  i would like to do the loop twice:

```
String ajout1 = "my adress";
        JSONObject json = null;
        String str = "";
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost(ajout1);
        try {
            response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
            str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            json = new JSONObject(str);
            String module = json.getJSONObject("1").getString("id_module");
            String address = json.getJSONObject("1").getString("adresse_mac");
            String mdp = json.getJSONObject("1").getString("mot_de_passe");
            String nom = json.getJSONObject("1").getString("name");

            String module2 = json.getJSONObject("2").getString("id_module");  //from 2nd object
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO test21 (mac,mdp,obj,puce) VALUES('"+address+"','"+mdp+"','"+nom+"','"+module+"');");




        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

my Json looks like this :

```
{
"1": {
    "id_module": "f83d6101cc",
    "adresse_mac": "00:6A:8E:16:C6:26",
    "mot_de_passe": "mp0001",
    "name": "a"
 },
"2": {
    "id_module": "64eae5403b",
    "adresse_mac": "00:6A:8E:16:C6:26",
    "mot_de_passe": "mp0002",
    "name": "a"
 }
}
```

Comment: have you tried: getJSONArray()

Answer (score 0):

Use the following way to parse

```
 try {

       json = new JSONObject(str);
       Iterator<String> it=json.keys();
       while(it.hasNext()){
          String key=it.next();// 'key' contains values like 1 ,2 etc..
          JSONObject element=json.getJSONObject("key");
          //Perform your parsing...
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Alternately (as indicated to you) its a **better** idea to use JSONArray.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the keys() method of the JSONObject, the method retrieve you a Iterator of Strings with the keys contained in the object.

You only need add a while like this:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = json.keys();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    String key = iterator.next();
    JSONObject jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(key);
    //All you other code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do I suppose:

```
JSONArray getInfo = yourJsonObject.getJSONArray();
```

then loop through using something like this
    while(i < getInfo.length()){
        //do stuffs here
    }

and that will loop through however many JSONObject you have